# htaccess - Fetch static content from different path if page is HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, static

As per the guidelines to speed up site, I have off-loaded all my static content (JS|CSS|IMAGES) to a subdomain static.example.com. 
The site is working fine but the problem arises when I load the secure pages. Browser throws a warnings for "InsecureContent" being loaded into my page.
We have ssl for only root domain not subdomain. I can't get another one but want to handle it this way. As the subdomain folder can be accessed inside the root folder i want this.

I want to handle this with .htaccess this way ->
When referer is https ://www.example.com/anything.php
Rewrite http ://static.example.com/folder/file.ex to https ://www.example.com/static/folder/file.ex

Somebody help me doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to help at all. In order for anything inside an htaccess file to get processed, the request has to have been *received* by the webserver. When your browser pops up the "Insecure Content" warning, it *hasn't sent the request yet*. This warning pops up when negotiating the SSL connection, and in your case, your cert doesn't cover the domain the request is being made to. That means adding any sort of redirect on the server's end isn't going to help. You're still going to see the warning.

You need to ensure that your content points to `http://static.example.com/` somehow, by either using a relative URI base or maybe absolute URLs that explicitly point to `http://`.

Another option may be to use some kind of javascript on the client side.

Comment: See it as when I get a request to server https://www.example.com/secure.php I want to change all the links that are on the page from http://static.example.com to https://www.example.com/static, before serving the page.

Comment: @VenomVipes rewrites and redirects only apply to requests to determine what gets served. If you want to dynamically modify content before it gets sent to a browser you can't use rewrites or htaccess, you're looking for something far more complicated and difficult: [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/)